# Javascript beginner. Get all properties of javascript object

Tags: javascript

let's suppose I have the following object:

```
k = {
  name : 'Sam',
  age : 20,
  interests : " ... "
  friends: " ... "
};
```

How to get all the objects properties without using the Object.keys() function in the ouptup format:

```
['name', 'age', 'interests' ...]
```

**Note: don't mark my question as duplicate and provide a link to an answer with the Object.keys() function**

Comment: So did you look at the Polyfill for Object.keys?

Comment: Don't want to use `Object.keys()` then use `for..in` loop

Comment: how to use the loop to access the keys?

Comment: Alternative duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var keys = [];
for (var key in k){
    keys.push(key);
}
```

For more complicated objects than your example, you may want to check k.hasOwnProperty(key) in that loop before adding it.

Comment: I need the keys but not values

Comment: key in this example is the key. I had a typo where I wasn't pushing it but that's corrected.

Comment: thank you! in 5 min I will mark it as an accepted answer